# How to return all ranges that are not included in any other range C# list

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, subset

I have a List of value `Tuple` as follows:

```
List<(int, int)> values = new List<(int, int)>
{
  (12, 15),
  (18, 30),
  (18, 27),
  (27, 30)
};
```

Now I want to remove the pairs in this list, which is inside the range of the wider pair.

For example: `(18, 27)` and `(27, 30)` are in the range of `(18, 30)`. So, I want to remove those pairs which lie under it.

So the final output must be:

```
(12, 15)
(18, 30)
```

I was thinking of removing those pairs using the `.RemoveAll()` method of LINQ but I am stuck as how to do so.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `.RemoveAll()` is actually a method of `List`, and not a `LINQ` method. I'm not sure I understand your criteria for moving items. Why should (18, 27) and (27, 30) be removed?

Comment: @john I want to remove the pairs which lie under a bigger pair, like `(18, 27)` and `(27, 30)` both lie under the pair `(18, 30)`.

Comment: Could you explain that: *(18, 30) contains both (18, 27) and (27, 30)*?

Comment: Why  (18, 30) is bigger than (27, 30)?

Comment: So can we conclude that these pairs are ranges, and that if a bigger range exists to fully encompass another pair, then the smaller pair should be removed? So if you had (2, 4) and (1, 5), then (2, 4) would be removed?

Comment: @NicklausBrain the pair `(18, 30)` contains is inclusive of both the pairs `(18, 27)` and `(27, 30)`

Comment: @john yes, if the bigger range is inclusive of the smaller ranges, go and remove it.

Comment: if `(18, 30)` contains `(27, 30)`. Does it contain `(30, 27)` too?

Comment: @Mark No it does not contain `(30, 27)`, but that pair should also be removed, as its just a swap of the original `(27, 30)`

Comment: What output would you expect from the following? `(1, 2) (3, 4) (5, 6) (7, 8) (0, 9) (10, 100)`. From your description, it would appear that the unmodified list would be returned for that example.

Comment: @MatthewWatson in that case it would remove all the pairs that lie under `(0, 9)` and the final pairs should be: `(0, 9)` and `(10, 100)`

Comment: So why would it choose `(0, 9)` rather than the much larger range `(10, 100)`? You are missing some details from your specification. Should it check which range encompasses the highest count of subranges, and use that one? The problem with your specification is the undefined term `biggest pair`. If there are two ranges which contain the same number of subranges, which should it choose? The largest of those two? Or the first?

Comment: @MatthewWatson `(0,9)` is a distinct pair which contains all pairs `(1, 2) (3, 4) (5, 6) (7, 8)` and `(10,100)` does not lie in the range `(0, 9)`

Comment: You misunderstand my question. WHY do you choose the `(0, 9)` as the "biggest pair" when `(10, 100)` is a bigger range? What would be the result given `(1, 2) (3, 4) (5, 6) (7, 8) (0, 9) (11, 12) (13, 14) (15, 16) (10, 100)`, say?

Comment: @MatthewWatson it should be 'wider pair' rather than 'biggest pair'. I think he describes it wrong. so the question was to delete each pair, if there is a wider pair exist.

Comment: @MatthewWatson if im not mistaken, your question's answer would be `(0, 9) (11, 12) (13, 14) (15, 16) (10, 100)`

Comment: @Mark `(10, 100)` encompasses the pairs `(11, 12), (13, 14), (15, 16)`. So the answer should be: `(0, 9)` and `(10, 100)`.

Comment: The clearer way of stating the requirement would therefore be: `Return all ranges that are not included in any other range`.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee oops, i missed that

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly this will do the trick. It compares each value of the list with the entire list till it finds another tuple where it falls within the range that's not exactly equal.

```
List<(int, int)> values = new List<(int, int)>
{
    (12, 15),
    (18, 30),
    (18, 27),
    (27, 30)
};

values.RemoveAll(x => values.Any(y => x.CompareTo(y) != 0 && x.Item1 >= y.Item1 && x.Item2 <= y.Item2));
```

Comment: If the `(30, 27)` is also present in the list, its actually an inversion of `(27, 30)` and is present in the range `(18, 30)`. Will it remove the pair `(30, 27)`

Comment: It will if there's any pair where 1 of both values falls in between the `(30, 27)` (so even a `(100,30)` would be removed in that case. If that's not what you want to happen and the `(30, 27)` should be treated as a `(27, 30)` I would recommend just switching them.

Comment: As example for switching values around: `var sorted = values.Select(x => x.Item1 > x.Item2 ? (x.Item2, x.Item1) : x).ToList();`

Comment: as a question `y => x.CompareTo(y)` why have you included that?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee so that an item in the list does not delete itself when compared to itself or a duplicate of itself

Comment: Consider using `values = values.Distinct()` to deal with the duplicate issue.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work and should be n*log(n):

```
//You will see some Math.Max and Math.Min - these are required because in your comments 
//you state the pairs can be out of order (the second value is less than the first)

int upper = int.MinValue;
values = values
    //Group all pairs by their minimum value, so (18,30) and (18,27) for example 
    //would be processed together
    .GroupBy(x => Math.Min(x.Item1, x.Item2))
    //Sort the groups based on their minimum value, so they can be processed in order. 
    //Although your example does not require this, the comments say this is required.
    .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
    //From the group [which may contain (18,30) and (18,27) for example],
    //only choose the one with the highest max value. This will choose (18,30)
    .Select(x => x.OrderBy(y => Math.Max(y.Item1, y.Item2)).Last())
    //Now iterate through the items and throw away the items which are inside
    //a pair previously processed pair. We use the upper variable to
    //keep track of the greatest processed upper bound to make throwing away 
    //previously processed pairs easy
    .Where(x =>
    {
        var max = Math.Max(x.Item1, x.Item2);
        if (upper < max)
        {
            upper = max;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }).ToList();
```

This can certainly be made faster without Linq, depending on how important memory and performance are for your application.

Comment: Can you describe the approach taken, seems a little bit verbose.

Comment: I added some comments. It is more verbose than the n^2 solution. You will often have options to solve a problem with n^2 or n*log(n) or n, and you'll generally find that that n^2 is easy to write, n*log(n) is a bit harder, and n you need to get very clever. You'll need to think about your application and which of these is the best option for you considering a balance of speed, memory, and readability.